# Jetpack Compose Row horizontalArrangement constraint

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How to satisfy both `spacedBy(8.dp)` and `.End`

```
Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)) {

}
```

```
Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding `Spacer` as the first row element with `weight` modifier is equivalent of `Arrangement.End`:

```
Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)) {
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
    Box(
        Modifier
            .size(30.dp)
            .background(Color.Red))
    Box(
        Modifier
            .size(30.dp)
            .background(Color.Green))
}
```

If you need to layout your other items with `weight` modifier, you can wrap it in one more `Row`:

```
Row {
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
    Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)) {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .size(30.dp)
                .background(Color.Red)
        )
        Box(
            Modifier
                .size(30.dp)
                .background(Color.Green)
        )
    }
}
```